# Modifying the micronaut tracing HttpClientSender DEFAULT_PATH to allow data send to New Relic Trace API

Tags: java, newrelic, micronaut, zipkin

Micronaut has a zipkin tracing library where you can easily override the zipkin server http endpoint like this:

```
tracing:
  zipkin:
    enabled: true
    http:
      urls: https://trace-api.eu.newrelic.com/trace/
```

Now by default it adds `DEFAULT_PATH = "/api/v2/spans"` to it, but for new relic the entire path should be like:

```
https://trace-api.eu.newrelic.com/trace/v1?Api-Key={INSERT_API_KEY}&Data-Format=zipkin&Data-Format-Version=2
```

I tried with Bean replacement and factories, but I just cannot find a proper clean solution.

The only solution I have found is by copying the entire `public final class HttpClientSender extends Sender` class  as `public final class NewRelicSender extends Sender` and just modifying the constructor:

```
public NewRelicSender(
            HttpClientConfiguration clientConfiguration,
            Provider<LoadBalancerResolver> loadBalancerResolver) {

        this.loadBalancerResolver = loadBalancerResolver;
        this.clientConfiguration = clientConfiguration;
        this.encoding = Encoding.JSON;
        this.messageMaxBytes = 5 * 1024;
        this.compressionEnabled = true;
        this.endpoint = URI.create("https://trace-api.eu.newrelic.com/trace/v1?Api-Key={INSERT_API_KEY}&Data-Format=zipkin&Data-Format-Version=2");
    }
```

It does work, but I feel like there is a better way to do this. I am copying almost 300 lines of code to replace 1.

What would be the Micronaut way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I contributed to Micronaut and submitted a PR, which is now merged.
[Pull request](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/pull/4873)